# Cannot get correct audio files to play from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, audio

When I tap on any of my cells in my table view they all play the same song in the first array. How do I make them play the song that is assigned to their individual array? The func automaticPlay() is responsible for dealing with the audio on this vc. When the cell is tapped the song should play automatically.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import AVFoundation

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableViewProducts: UITableView!
    var delegate: ListViewController?

    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    let audioStuffed = false
    let audioPlayer = AVPlayer()
    var postData = [productsList]()
    var player: AVPlayer!


    func automaticPlay() {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let audioUp = postData[indexPath.row].audio
        let url = audioUp

        player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url!)!)

        player.volume = 1.0
        player.rate = 1.0
        if player.rate == 0 {
            player.play()
            print("It's Playing")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("AudioDB")
        loadProducts()

        do {
            try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postData.count
    }

    func loadProducts() {
        ref?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newSweets = [productsList]()

            for post in snapshot.children {
                let postObject = productsList(snapshot: post as! DataSnapshot)
                newSweets.append(postObject)
                print(self.postData)

            }
            self.postData = newSweets
            self.tableViewProducts.reloadData()
        }) { (error:Error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }

    //This places the text on the ViewControllerTableViewCell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let sweet = postData[indexPath.row]

        cell.idLbl.text = sweet.id
        cell.nameLbl.text = sweet.p_name

        if let profileImageUrl = sweet.image{
            let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.productImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
        return cell
    }

    var selectedRowIndex = -1

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
            automaticPlay()
            return 200 //Expanded
        }
        return 40//Not expanded
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
            selectedRowIndex = -1

        } else {
            selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `automaticPlay` from `heightForRowAt` is a really, really bad idea. Do not do that.

Comment: @rmaddy For an explanation: `heightForRowAt` will call itself multiple times and you do not have control over it, so it's possible that it will "randomly" restart.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for the Info! Sorry guys kinda new to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenters are correct.  You are calling automaticPlay from the wrong place.  Call it from didSelectRowAt, and remove the line defining indexPath in automaticPlay.  Instead use the indexPath you get passed in didSelectRowAt.